# How to add/subtract two textbox values and display the output in another text box in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I havent been able to get the result to display in the third textbox "num3". Is it because I don't have the sum function in the "export default function"? I tried doing that and adding other return statements but nothing works. Am I missing something?

```
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
      txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
  if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
      txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

  var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + 
parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('num3').value = result;
  }

}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number 1</h2>
      <input type ="text" id="num1" onkeyup="sum();" />
      <h3>Number 2</h3>
      <input type ="text" id="num2" onkeyup="sum();" />
      <div></div>
      <button id ="add"> Add </button>
      <div></div>
      <button> Subtract </button>
      <div></div>
      <input type ="text" id="num3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Jason, please share code , instead of screenshot to replicate and debug easily

Comment: you should avoid any DOM operation when you use react. use `useState` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

```js
export default function App() {
  const sum = () => {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    if (txtFirstNumberValue == "") txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
    if (txtSecondNumberValue == "") txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById("num3").value = result;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number 1</h2>
      <input type="text" id="num1" onKeyUp={sum} />
      <h3>Number 2</h3>
      <input type="text" id="num2" onKeyUp={sum} />
      <div></div>
      <button id="add"> Add </button>
      <div></div>
      <button> Subtract </button>
      <div></div>
      <input type="text" id="num3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`onKeyup` instead of onkeyup and wrap the function with  `{ }` not `" "`

#### A Better Answer

HERE IS THE CODE : https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-tesla-4yxr9m?file=/src/App.js:0-1158

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [isPlus, setIsPlus] = useState(true);
  const [inputOne, setInputOne] = useState(0);
  const [inputTwo, setInputTwo] = useState(0);
  const calResult = useMemo(
    function cal() {
      return isPlus
        ? Number(inputOne) + Number(inputTwo)
        : Number(inputOne) - Number(inputTwo);
    },
    [inputOne, inputTwo, isPlus]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Number 1</h2>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="num1"
        value={inputOne}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setInputOne(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <h3>Number 2</h3>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="num2"
        value={inputTwo}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setInputTwo(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <div></div>
      <button id="add" onClick={() => setIsPlus(true)}>
        {" "}
        Add{" "}
      </button>
      <div></div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlus(false)}> Subtract </button>
      <div></div>
      <input type="text" id="num3" value={calResult} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The HOOKS like `useState` , `useMemo`, `useEffect` are the core concept of the react. Highly recommend figure out that part first.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using useRef react hook rather than document.tgetElementById for DOM manipulations.

1. import userRef from react
   `import { useRef } from "react";`
2. Initialize a new ref inside a component in below format
    `const num1Ref = useRef(0)`
3. Input value can get and set the value of the ref by accessing the .current property of the ref object
   `num1Ref.current.value`

Sample working code for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-butterfly-5lr1d5?file=/src/App.js:0-998

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const num1Ref = useRef(0);
  const num2Ref = useRef(0);
  const num3Ref = useRef(0);
  function sum() {
    let txtFirstNumberValue = num1Ref.current.value;
    let txtSecondNumberValue = num2Ref.current.value;
    txtFirstNumberValue = txtFirstNumberValue ? txtFirstNumberValue : 0;
    txtSecondNumberValue = txtSecondNumberValue ? txtSecondNumberValue : 0;
    let result =
      parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue, 10) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue, 10);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      num3Ref.current.value = result;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Number 1</div>
      <input type="text" ref={num1Ref} id="num1" onKeyUp={sum} />
      <div>Number 2</div>
      <input type="text" ref={num2Ref} id="num2" onKeyUp={sum} />
      <div>
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Subtract</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" ref={num3Ref} id="num3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```